# How can i navigate from one screen to another after the progress bar has completed

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

Below is the .py file for the code- the next screen is defined and all related import dome. This works with other .kv files

```
from kivy.animation import Animation
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen


def go_next_screen(self):
    self.index = (self.index + 1) % len(self.available_screens)
    screen = self.load_screen(self.index)
    sm = self.root.ids.sm
    sm.switch_to(screen, direction='left')
    self.current_title = screen.name
```

Below is the .kv file which has the progress bar, once the bar is 100% I want the page to navigate to the next one automatically.

```
ShowcaseScreen:
name: 'A'

    Label:
        text: 'Progression: {}%'.format(int(pb.value))
        size_hint_y: None
        height: '48dp'

    ProgressBar:
        id: pb
        size_hint_x: .5
        size_hint_y: None
        height: '48dp'
        value: (app.time * 10) % 100.
        if (int(value > 90)) : app.go_next_screen()
```

Answer (score 0):

u check if the bar has reached the limit you want and just call the next_screen method there.

Comment: am totally new to Kivy, can you be more elaborate and if possible give me a code to solve this.